# How to write a self join query in drupal 7 using db_select

Tags: database

I want to write a self join query, However I dunno how to write it in drupal 7 using `db_select()`.

The query will look like this

> SELECT * FROM msg where sender = receiver

Both sender and receiver fields are part of the `msg` table.

Comment: we can achieve it using the following query.

db_select('msg')
  ->fields('msg')
  ->where('sender = receiver');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible with the following query,

```
db_select('msg')
  ->fields('msg')
  ->where('sender = receiver');
```

Answer (score 4):

A query using `db_select` is a lot slower than a 'vanilla' `db_query` call...for a query as simple as the one you're doing just run it through db_query:

```
$query = db_query('SELECT * FROM msg where sender = receiver');
```